# docker run not working with entrypoint.sh and command in exec form

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker entrypoint file like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
echo 'starting docker'  
echo $PWD
exec "$@"  
#exec uwsgi --ini server.ini
```

and a CMD instruction in docker file like :

```
CMD ["-exec","uwsgi --ini server.ini"]
```

On running, it says that

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 4: exec: -e: invalid option

What is not correct here? Shouldn't the exec form(json) of CMD work here ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CMD ["uwsgi --ini server.ini"]` or `CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "server.ini"]`

Comment: It's really not clear why you expect this syntax to work.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I get `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 11: exec: uwsgi --ini server.ini: not found`

Comment: @tripleee  even `CMD ["uwsgi --ini server.ini"]` is not working

Comment: Try the second one i gave that should work

Comment: yes working, but why is the exec form not working?

Comment: Because it's invalid. Again, where did you get the impression that `-exec` is a valid thing to put there?

Comment: Because you call on first case becomes like `exec -exec 'uwsgi --ini server.ini'`, which is not a valid command

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below

```
CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "server.ini"]
```

When you use `CMD ["-exec","uwsgi --ini server.ini"]` you actual command on shell is executed like below

```sh
$ exec -exec 'uwsgi --ini server.ini'
```

Which is not a valid command